# Always gets kicked out of the sub?

Tags: excel, vba, function, loops, syntax-error

Every time I run this loop, as soon as VBA executes the clear contents, I always get kicked-out of the sub in Module 5 and end-up in Module 2 to an RGB function that has nothing to do with the loop !

I've been messing around for a while but it seems like I can't find the solution !
I has been going on for a while ... Ignoring it didn't change anything ;-)

Has anyone ever seen this issue ?

```
Do While Line >= 1
  set WS_TREATED_DATA = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("TREATED_DATA")
  Range("A" & Line & ":" & "I" & Line).ClearContents
Loop
```

Comment: Why do you need a loop to clear contents?

Comment: I need to remove the content ONLY of the range I need to keep the formatting and the formulas that are farther to the right.

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't mean you need to loop. Just clear contents of the entire range in question, without looping.

Answer (score 1):

I bet your `RGB` function is a UDF that is used in (invoked by) one or more cells.

When you `ClearContents` on <s>WS_TREATED_DATA</s> *whatever worksheet is active* (`Range` being unqualified does that), it causes a recalc on that sheet, and if any user-defined function (UDF) is involved in the recalc, it will be invoked. Execution will then resume to the `Loop` statement, after all worksheet events have processed.

If you want to defer recalculation until after the loop, set `Application.Calculation` to `xlCalculationManual`, and set it back to `xlCalculationAutomatic` when you're ready to recalculate. If you have event handlers running code when a worksheet is modified, you need to toggle `Application.EnableEvents` to disable these event handlers.

That said, [BigBen is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58808339/always-gets-kiked-out-os-the-sub#comment103896029_58808339), you don't need a loop here... and unless some code is missing, that loop is infinite (`Line` is never incremented).

Comment: The loop is required because I  need to loop through lines of data to erase from the report. I replaced the IF statement because I was in the impression that the error was coming from there ! ... I will put the If statement instead... more appropriate here Thanks